# How can I simply check if a set of n numbers are all different?

Tags: math, numbers, logic

I have n integers and I need a quick logic test to see that they are all different, and I don't want to compare every combination to find a match...any ideas on a nice and elegant approach?

I don't care what programming language your idea is in, I can convert!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to check every combination thanks to commutivity and transitivity; you can simply go down the list and check each entry against each entry that *comes after it*.  For example:

```
bool areElementsUnique( int[] arr ) {
    for( int i=0; i<arr.Length-1; i++ ) {
        for( int j=i+1; j<arr.Length; j++ ) {
            if( arr[i] == arr[j] ) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that the inner loop doesn't start from the beginning, but from the next element (`i+1`).

Answer (score 7):

Use a set data structure if your language supports it, you might also look at keeping a hash table of seen elements.

In python you might try

```
seen={}
n_already_seen=n in seen
seen[n]=n
```

`n_already_seen` will be a boolean indicating if n has already been seen.

Comment: I feel absolutely silly for posting an answer that is just a longer version of yours. I totally didn't notice, and I'm really sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Hash Table or a Set type of data structure that using hashing. Then you can insert all of the elements into the hashtable or hashset, and either as you insert, check if the element is already in the table/set. If for some reason you don't want to check as you go, you can just insert all the numbers and then check to see if the size of the structure is less than n. If it is less than n, there had to be repeated elements. Otherwise, they were all unique.

Here is a really compact Java solution. The time-complexity is amortized O(n) and the space complexity is also O(n).

```
public boolean areAllElementsUnique(int [] list)
{
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int number: list)
        if (set.contains(number))
            return false;
        else
            set.add(number);
    return true;
}
```